# Next field key on Android keyboard

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have an Android device with an integrated barcode scanner. It is configured to add a `tab` character suffix so that focus should **move to the next field** in a form, but it fails to do so. Instead, an actual `tab` character is inserted in the text itself.

I know Android keyboard has a `next` key to navigate to next input, but I can't find the machine code it uses to provide it as a suffix for the barcode scanner. Any help wouldbe very much appreciated.

I'm not actually developping the app, but configuring the barcode scanner. The form works fine with `tab` on a computer.

Comment: If it is html, is the appropriate tabindex set for each element? [Web technology for developersSee HTML: HyperText Markup LanguageSee Global attributestabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) If it is not html, please check the settings supported by the programming language/framework you are using.

Comment: I'm not actually developping the app, but configuring the barcode scanner. The form works fine with `tab` on a computer.

Comment: Your application may have customized the handling of the TAB key. You should check the specifications of the application.